# How to send optional arguments to another function/method?

Tags: c, objective-c

I have an designated initializer with optional arguments (similar to the following code), and I want to create an autorelease method by calling it. Is there any way to do this?

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

- (id)initWithArgs:(id)firstArg, ...;
+ (id)objectWithArgs:(id)firstArg, ...;

@end

@implementation MyObject

- (id)initWithArgs:(id)firstArg, ...
{
    if (!firstArg || ![super init]) {
        return nil
    }

    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, firstArg);

    id currentObject = firstArg;
    do {
        NSLog(@"%@", currentObject);
    } while ((currentObject = va_arg(argList, id)) != nil);

    va_end(argList);
    return self;
}

+ (id)objectWithArgs:(id)firstArg, ...
{
    // return [[[MyObject alloc] initWithArgs:firstArg, ...] autorelease];
}

@end
```

Comment: next time search the site first, there's tons of duplicates for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it.  See the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html).  The closest thing you can do is to create two versions of your functions, one which takes varargs (`...`), and one which takes a `va_list`.  The varargs version can then pass off the work to the `va_list` version to avoid duplicate code:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

- (id)initWithArgs:(id)firstArg, ...;
- (id)init:(id)firstArg withVaList:(va_list)args;
+ (id)objectWithArgs:(id)firstArg, ...;
+ (id)object:(id)firstArg withVaList:(va_list)args;

@end

@implementation MyObject

- (id)initWithArgs:(id)firstArg, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstArg);
    id result = [self init:firstArg withVaList:args];
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}

- (id)init:(id)firstArg withVaList:(va_list)args
{
    // do actual init here:
    while((id arg = va_arg(args, id)))
    {
        // ...
    }
}

+ (id)objectWithArgs:(id)firstArg, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstArg);
    id result = [MyObject object:firstArg withVaList:args];
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}

+ (id)object:(id)firstArg withVaList:(va_list)args
{
    return [[[MyObject alloc] init:firstArg withVaList:args] autorelease];
}

@end
```

Comment: how should - (id)initWithVaList:(va_list)args iterate over the args ?
this is what i tried.
id eachObject; 
while (eachObject = va_arg(args, id))

result is when i do this the first argument is not to find in that while-loop..

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to do default arguments in languages with method overloading is:

```
function foo(bar, baz) {
  ... actual function code here ...
}

function foo(bar) {
  foo(bar, 42)
}
```